# Changing method from Dictionary to Struct

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have the method below where I use a `Dictionary` to set two values nl. **Id** and **Name**/ `key` and `value`. Now I understand that a Dictionary can only take ***two*** values, but what I need is change my method so that I can allow more values to be added to my Type. What would be the best way to do this?

```
public Dictionary<int, string> GetQuoteOptionList(QuoteOptionType optionType)
{
    Dictionary<int, string> result = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    using (TruckDb db = new TruckDb())
    {
        switch (optionType)
        {
            case QuoteOptionType.BodyType:
                db.BodyTypes.ToList().ForEach(x => result.Add(x.Id, x.Name));
                break;
                ...
            case QuoteOptionType.RearDropSide:
                db.RearDropSides.ToList().ForEach(x => result.Add(x.Id, x.Name));
                break;
            case QuoteOptionType.Extras://Example: (x.Id, x.Description, x.StockItem, x.MinimumStock) I would like to add more than just two values    
                db.Extras.ToList().ForEach(x => result.Add(x.Id, x.Description));
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("The option that was selected does not have a corresponding list.");
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I have an example in my code on what I want changed and I posted it above this, just check the `case QuoteOptionType.Extras:`

Thank you in advance for any help or advice! :)

Comment: Pls review your title, it is irritating. A struct would be of no use here. You should consider a List<string> for the second type of the dictionary, or a custom type.

Comment: would `Dictionary<int, tupple<T1, T2...>` suffice

Comment: or a dictionary of int and object, where your object holds your values. `Dictionary<int, Type>`

Comment: @user2946329 - Yes thank you very much, yours and the others answers helped me alot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class like this:

```
public class yourClass
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string StockItem { get; set; }
    public string MinimumStock { get; set; }
}

List<yourClass> result = new List<yourClass>();
db.Extras.ToList().ForEach(c => result.Add(new yourClass { ID="id" , Description="desc" , MinimumStock="minimum" , StockItem="stock" }));
```

Answer (score 1):

The choice of structure to use, Dictionary, List,... doesn't depend on the data you want to store but depend on constraints you have for insertion, search, sorting,..
If you use Dictionary, I guess you need to retrive item in fast way. You ca continue use dictionry and just replace value type from string to a new class :

```
public class NewClass
{
    public string Id{ get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    //......
}
db.Extras.ToList().ForEach(c => result.Add(x.Id, new NewClass(x.Id/*other field*/));
```